# How to access the data directly without using the each loops or any loop every time in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, arrays, express, mongoose, handlebars.js

Below is the code I have to use everytime which is working fine; means using the each loop and then using the if-else condition to fetch the particular element from the arraylist stored in mongoDB.

```
Mongoose arrayList Addtasks data schema:
Addtasks : [{
    topic: String,
    words: Number,
    keywords: String,
    website: String,
    otherdetails: String,
    exampleRadios: String,
    deadline: Date,
    Date: String,
    fileName: String,
    Bigpaths:[]
  }]


router.route('/profile/view/:id')
.get(function(req, res, next) {
  User.findOne({_id: req.user.id}, function(err, dataUser) {
      if (dataUser) {
          dataUser.Addtasks.forEach(element => {
            if(element._id == req.params.id)
            {
            res.render('viewTask',{mainData: element});
          }
        });
          }
          else {
          res.render('error');
        }
        });
})
```

I have tried this code but isn't working. May I know why we cant fetch the particular data in express using Mongoose directly this way like normally? Why this doesn't work?

```
router.route('/profile/view/:id')
.get(function(req, res, next) {
  User.findOne({_id: req.user.id}, function(err, dataUser) {
    
            if(dataUser.Addtasks[0].id == req.params.id)
            {
            res.render('viewTask',{mainData: dataUser.Addtasks[0].topic);
          }
   else {
          res.render('error');
        }
    
    }); 
        })
```

Comment: Could you post the error you are receiving?